# Mesh deforming when shrinkwrapping

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, workflow

I've read tutorials on getting 1 mesh to conform to the shape of another via a combination of mesh deforming to a flat plane (with a solidify mod setup but not applied), parenting the object to the flat plane, and then applying a shrinkwrap on the flat plane (above solidify in the stack).    As you can see below, this works, but also deforms my original mesh badly.

Setup:

[image]

and the result:

[image]

Altering the shrinkwrap mode doesn't resolve this, any help is appreciated!!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=shrinkwrap%20curve

Comment: The above provided answer was for a different issue.  I did end up resolving this by using a much higher subdivide count on both the flat plane as well as the sphere (256 x 256), which was the target of the shrinkwrap.  This took longer for the computer to process, but did end up with fairly spot on results.