# shrinkwrap modifier makes object flat

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers

So i made a cartoon squid and i want to add some suction cups, so i hit CNTRL+7 and aligned them to one of the tentacles, but now i need it to stick to the bottom, so i add a shrinkwrap modifier and it makes it flat which i need it to be thick, how can i fix this?

Here is a picture:
[image]

.blend file:

[image]

I have tried other ways but the suction cups hang over the tentacle and it wont "stick" to the tentacle..i have tried answers that are a duplicate of my question but i get the same results. I have tried latice, and shrinkwrap but to no avail.

I still have this problem.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77390/why-shrinkwrap-making-the-tube-flat and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95975/why-im-not-getting-thickness-with-shrinkwrap-modifier or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101715/mesh-deforming-when-shrinkwrapping

Comment: This may be a duplicate but the solutions are not working for me so i need something else.

Comment: @Optimus If solutions are not working for you please explain *why* they are not working.

Comment: I don't know why they are not working...@Ray Mairlot

Comment: Use a lattice to deform the object and add the swrinkwrap modifier to the lattice as explained here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95975/why-im-not-getting-thickness-with-shrinkwrap-modifier/96055#96055 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/how-to-add-curve-modifier-to-text/60958#60958 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55552/how-can-i-project-an-object-to-a-sphere/55606#55606 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48823/deform-object-after-another-object/48841#48841

Comment: @cegaton that is not working, it kind of works but then certain suction cups are not "sticking" to to tentacle like others...is there any other way? perhaps you can explain it in my blend file?

Comment: @Optimus perhaps *you* can explain clearly what you tried so far. It's hard to help you if your comments are only "its not working"